# Circle inscribed between two curves

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the plane region $S_n$ bounded from above and below for the graphs of $f_n(x)=x^{1/n}$ and $g_n(x)=x^n$, $0\le x\le1$.

How to find the radious and center of the circle inscribed in $S_n$?

Intuitively, the center is on the set $\{(A,A):0\le A\le 1\}$, so we can think the problem finding the value of $A$ and $r$ such that the equation $(x-A)^2+(x^n-A)^2=r^2$ has only one solution for $x$.

Another approach is parametrization, but equations are not easy to solve.

Is there any hint?

Answer (score 7):

I believe that there are  many circles inscribed in that region.  As everybody else noticed, the diagonal $y=x$ is  axis of symmetry of the region.   Fix $x_0\in(0,1)$.  Imagine that a (circular) planar wave is born at the point $(x_0,x_0)$ on the diagonal. It evolves as a growing circle centered at $(x_0,x_0)$. At the first moment the wave touches  the two curves it becomes a circle  inscribed in that region.Due to symmetry it touches both  graphs at the same time)

The MAPLE animation below illustrates the process. In the animation I chose  $n=4$, $x_0=0,75$.

[image]

So, if you choose the center of the circle  to be $(x_0,x_0)$ you are looking to find  the distance  from this point to the curve $y=x^n$.  In other words, you want to minimize the function
$$
f(x)=(x-x_0)^2+(x^n-x_0)^2.
$$
The radius of the inscribed circle centered at $(x_0,x_0)$ will then be

$$
r(x_0)=\Big(\;\min_{x\in [0,1]}(x-x_0)^2+(x^n-x_0)^2\;\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
The  equation 
$$
f'(x)=0  \;\Longleftrightarrow  2(x-x_0)+2nx^{n-1}(x^n-x_0)=0
\tag{1}
$$
describes a curve in the $(x,x_0)$ plane.  The  case $n=4$ is depicted below. (The parameter $x_0$ is measured on the vertical axis.)

[image]

More  concretely  we can solve (1) for $x_0$

$$ x_0(1+nx^{n-1})= x+nx^{2n-1} \implies x_0=\underbrace{\frac{x+nx^{2n-1}}{1+nx^{n-1}}}_{c(x)}. $$

This shows that we can predict the location of the  center of the circle given the location  of its  tangencies with the curve $y=x^n$.  For $n=10$ the graph of the function $c(x)$ is depicted below.

[image]

It shows that for $x_0$ (roughly) between $0.4$ and $0.55$ the function

$$ x\mapsto (x-x_0)^2+(x^n-x_0)^2 $$

has three critical points.  The figure below illustrates what happens when $n=10$  and $x_0=0.45$. We see that it has two local minima and a local max.   We depicted below the graph of this function for $n=10$ and $c=0.4$.

[image]

**Remark 1.** The  radius of the inscribed circle  has the form
$$
r(x)=\sqrt{\big(x-c(x)\big)^2+\big( x^n-c(x)\big)^2}.
$$
For the circle to be actually inscribed it is necessary that  $r(x)\leq c(x)$.

For $n=10$ the function $r(x)$ is depicted below, in red,  and the function $c(x)$,  in blue.

[image]

**Remark 2.**   The maximal radius $r_{\max}$ is the solution of the  min-max problem
$$
r_{\max}=\max_{y\in (0,1)}\min_{x\in (0,1)}\sqrt{F_n(x,y)},
$$

$$
F_n(x,y)=(x-y)^2+(x^n-y)^2
$$

This suggests looking  at the critical points of $F_n$. They are determined  by the equations

$$  (x-y)+nx^{n-1}(x^n-y)=0, \tag{2}$$

$$ y-x+y-x^n=0. \tag{3} $$

From (3) we deduce
$$ y=\frac{x+x^n}{2}. $$
Using this in (2) we deduce

$$ \frac{x-^n}{2}-nx^{n-1}\frac{x-x^n}{2} =0,$$

so

$$x=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-1}}=:t_n.  $$

The  center is located at $(c(t_n),c(t_n))$.  Recalling that $nt_n^{n-1}=1$ we  deduce

$$c(t_n)=\frac{t_n\big(1+nt_n^{2(n-1)}\big)}{1+nt_n^{n-1}}=\frac{t_n(1+t_n^{n-1})}{2}=\frac{n+1}{2n}t_n.$$

For $n=10$ we  deduce

$$t_n\approx 0.7742,\;\;c(t_n)\approx 0.4258 $$

and

$$
r(t_n)\approx 0.4927.
$$ 
 The circle of radius $r(t_n)$ centered at $(c(t_n),c(t_n))$ is not even contained in the first quadrant, yet it is tangent to $y=x^n$.  Thus the min-max approach does not yield $r_{\max}$ as indicated in one of  @ksoriano's  comments; see the figure below . depicting the circle of radius $r(t_n)$ centered at $(c(t_n), c(t_n))$, $n=10$.

[image]

The next figure  depicts in the case $n=10$ an inscribed  circle of radius $\approx 0.45$.  It  is tangent to $y=x^n$ at $x=0.9$  and $c(0.9)\approx 0.46$. Note that the radius of an inscribed circle is at most $0.5$ so the  situation below is nearly optimal.

[image]

It seems to me that, for large $n$,  there is a unique  largest inscribed  circle,  which  has four points of tangencies  with the graphs and  as $n\to \infty$ its radius converges  to $0.5$, the radius of the circle inscribed in the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

**Remark 3.** . Recall that the map $x\mapsto c(x)$  determines the location of the center tangent to $y=x^n$ at the point $(x,x^n)$. Its radius is $r(x)$. The plot of the $(c, r)$ curve $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$
$$
[0,1]\ni x\mapsto \big(\; c(x), r(x)\;\big)\in\bR^2,
$$
is   very revealing. Below we depict the case $n=10$.

[image]

The location of the center  is tracked on the horizontal axis.  As the center moves  along the  diagonal from $(0,0)$  to $(1,1)$ we notice various "phase transitions" or bifurcations. Imagine a vertical line moving from left to right in the above figure and keep track of the number of  points of intersection with  the $(c,r)$ curve.

Depending on the location of the center,  there are typically, either one, or three circles tangent to $y=x^n$.  To  detect $r_{\max}$ we need to keep track of the smallest of these circles. In the above plot  this means looking only at the bottom triangle of the $(c,r)$-curve.  The altitude of the top  vertex of this triangle is $r_\max$.

In any case,  the above figure suggests that the function 
$$
y\mapsto \min_{x\in[0,1]} F_n(x,y)
$$ 
is rather regular.

There exist  numbers $y_{\min}<y_{\max}$ in $(0,1)$ so that for $y\in[0,1]\setminus [y_{\min},y_{\max}]$ there exists only one circle centered at $(y,y)$ and tangent to the boundary of the region. $\newcommand{\pa}{\partial}$

As $y$ crosses  $y_{\min}$ increasingly the equation
$$
\pa_x F_n(x,y)=0
$$ 
undergoes a qualitative change: it goes from having one solution to having  three solutions.   It is a "birth" process.

As $y$ crosses  $y_{\max}$ increasingly, the above equation    goes from having three solutions to having one solution. It is a "death" process.

The points $y_{\min}$ and $y_{\max}$  are determined by solving the nonlinear system
$$
\pa_x F_n(x,y)=\pa^2_{xx}F_n(x,y)=0,
$$
i.e.,
$$
nx^{2n-1}-nx^{n-1}y+x-y=0,\;\;n(2n-1)x^{2n-2}+n(n-1)x^{n-2}y+1=0.
$$
I believe that for  $n$  large this system has three solutions
$$
(x_{\min},y_{\min}),\;\;(x_*,y_*),\;\;(x_{\max},y_{\max}),
$$
$$
y_{\min}<y_*<y_{\max}.
$$
The center of the larges inscribed  circle is located  $(y_*,y_*)$ and  its radius  is
$$
r_{\max}=r(x_*).
$$
The number of solutions of the system is  the number of roots in $(0,1)$ of the equation
$$
(2n-1)x^{2n-2}+(n-1)x^{n-2}c(x)+\frac{1}{n}=0.
$$
This reduces to a polynomial equation. Theoretically, the number of solutions of a real polynomial equation in a given interval can be determined using the classical [Sturm theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thanks. But what if I'm searching for $r_{\max}$? That is, the maximum circle incribed.

Comment: I've added a remark about $r_{\max}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the curves constitute to a function and its inverse, as is the case in your example, then you have to check pairs of points $p:=(x_a,f(x_a)),\ q:=(x_b,f^{-1}(x_b))=(f(x_a),x_a)$, so that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x_a)=1=\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x_b)\quad \wedge\quad \frac{f^{-1}(x_b)-f(x_a)}{x_b-x_a}=-1$$
if, as is the case in your example, the region defined by the two curves is also convex, that pair of points is unique and thus $(p,q)$ marks a diameter of the largest contained circle and thus $p=((\frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{n-1},(\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{n}{n-1}}),\ q=((\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{n}{n-1}},(\frac{1}{n})^\frac{1}{n-1})$ define the pair of points in which the largest contained circle touches both curves; the diameter equals the distance of $p$ and $q$

Comment: for n=10 it fails.

Comment: Yes, I added a similar answer before noticing that while I was writing it this one was already posted. But it is possible that the largest circle has four contact points with the two curves rather than contacting it only at the two points of a diameter, and when this happens the solution is more complicated.

Comment: @DavidEppstein yes, I completely missed the check for the curvature in the contact points; I'll leave my answer as an instructive example of how important careful analysis is...